# How to export data in CSV into DOS\Windows Format in PHP?

Tags: php, csv, export

I have an export in PHP like this :

```
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="agents_list.csv"');
```

When I make export, Notepad++ inform me that the format is "Macintosh" (CR). I need to have it in "Dos\Windows" (CR+LF) format.
How can I do that ? Must I modify some header ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you generate the file yourself? If yes then use CR+LF as newlines.

Comment: Yes, this is a PHP script, and new lines are created by \r

Comment: Okay you give me a response element ^^ I've modify the \r by \r\n and now export format is correctly set to Dos\Windows. Good to know this tip :) Thank you for your help

Comment: @JGrunder you answered yourself. \r == CR (aka Mac style). replace by `\r\n` and this is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced \r == CR (aka Mac style) with \r\n that is DOS format. Thank you @Andrey for your suggestion that makes me in way to find the solution.